# How to do Partition algorithm in php

Tags: php

I tried getting partition of numbers in PHP.

For example, 
number 10, divide like 4, 3, 3. 
if 14 then 5, 5, 4

this type of partition

Comment: what is this ?? 10 could be {1,1, 8}, {2,2,6}, {3,3,4}, {4, 4,2}, {5,5,0} You are the one who define the rule ..

Comment: It is not related to php. It is question about general algorithm for partition of numbers. Add tags to your question relating algorithms. You can read about partition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division and one of simple and basic algorithm here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet :

```
<?php

$number = 14;
$limit = 3;


$rem = $number%$limit;

$divi = floor($number/$limit);

$part = array();

for($i=0; $i<$rem; $i++) {
   $part[$i] = $divi+1;
}

for($i=$rem; $i<$limit; $i++) {
   $part[$i] = $divi;
}

//$part[$rem+1] = $divi;

print_r($part);

?>
```